# PHP-SOAP SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document

Tags: php, web-services, soap

i'm currently testing and playing with webservices on my localhost. I got the "SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document" in the client call of my program and i can't seem to find the reason why.

I've already changed the encoding to UTF8 without BOM (as it was suggested on other questions) and still nothing. I think it might be because of the complextype i have in my wsdl specification.

Here's the part of the wsdl that i think that matters:

```
<types>
<xsd:schema targetNamesace="urn:consulta">
    <xsd:simpleType name="codigo">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="255"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="designacao">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="255"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="unidades">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="255"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>   
    <xsd:simpleType name="quantidade">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal">
            <xsd:minLength value="2"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="18"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>   
    <xsd:simpleType name="referencia">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="255"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:complexType name="MapaQuantidades">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="codigo" type="tns:codigo"/>
            <xsd:element name="designacao" type="tns:designacao"/>
            <xsd:element name="unidades" type="tns:unidades"/>
            <xsd:element name="quantidade" type="tns:quantidade"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
```

And the code i'm using on the client:

```
    $wsdl= "....";

$soap_options = array(
    'trace'       => 1,     // traces let us look at the actual SOAP messages later
    'exceptions'  => 1 );

$cliente = new SoapClient($wsdl, $soap_options);

$mapaQtds = new StdClass();
$mapaQtds->MapaQuantidades = new StdClass();
$mapaQtds->MapaQuantidades->codigo = 'Codigo WS';
$mapaQtds->MapaQuantidades->designacao = 'Designacao WS';
$mapaQtds->MapaQuantidades->unidades = 'Unidades WS';
$mapaQtds->MapaQuantidades->quantidade = 20;

$soapstruct = new SoapVar($mapaQtds, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);

$referencia = "Referencia WS";
$designacao = "Designacao Principal";

try{

    $valor = $cliente->create_consulta( $referencia, $designacao, $soapstruct);
    //echo "Resultado = " . $valor;
    echo "REQUEST:\n" . $client->__getLastRequestHeaders() . "\n";

}catch(SoapFault $e){
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Currently, the function on the server is only returning true... but it seems that the program doesn't even reach the server. It "dies" in $client->create_consulta. Any idea on why this is happening?

The full error is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document     in C:\xampp\htdocs\Integration\Agregation\WSConsultaClient.php:30 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Integration\Agregation\WSConsultaClient.php(30): SoapClient->__call('create_consulta', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Integration\Agregation\WSConsultaClient.php(30): SoapClient->create_consulta('Referencia WS', 'Designacao Prin...', Object(SoapVar)) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Integration\Agregation\WSConsultaClient.php on line 30
```

Thx in advance,
CR

Answer (score 0):

Check your server code, i have the same problem and I solve it removing every echo, ?>, and html code in the page, your server.php must be a blank page

Comment: Could you maybe cut and paste the applicable code and what you did that fixed it?